# Finding a regex to match HTML

Tags: html, regex

I'm trying to find a regex pattern to use with this example to match only the number values after /p/

```
/store/shop/en/model/brand/Heisman-On/p/15890735"target="">Heisman-on
/store/shop/en/model/brand/Heisman/p/03518616"target="">Heisman
/store/shop/en/model/brand/2tee-Cove3/p/67834675"target="">2tee-Cove3
```

such as :

> 15890735
>
> 03518616
>
> 67834675

Comment: By using Javascript?

Comment: a bit more context required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do the trick:

`\/p\/(\d+)`

**[Here](https://regex101.com/r/sD6vU9/1)** is a preview.
Use the first capturegroup.

Here's a way you could get the numbers:

```
var input = '/store/shop/en/model/brand/Heisman-On/p/15890735"target="">Heisman-on';
var regex = /\/p\/(\d+)/;
var numbers = regex.exec(input)[1];
console.log(numbers); // Output: 15890735
```

Comment: Thank you, however that also retrieves the /p/, I wish to only retrieve the numbers after /p/

Comment: No you can use the first capturegroup to point to the digits only. I'll add an example in javascript.

Comment: oops sorry didn't see your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`/(?:\/p\/)(\d+)/i`

http://regexr.com/3blr5

Your aim would be for the `$1` output